# Navigation Bar changes bar on it's own

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController containing UITAbleView in it.

[image]

I use block to push new view from view controller:

```
_noviyVC.presentPlease = ^(UIViewController *controller)
{
    [weakself.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
};

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ProfileVCC *profile = [[ProfileVCC alloc] init];
    profile.userId = _users[indexPath.row][@"id"];

    if (self.presentPlease)
    {
        self.presentPlease(profile);
    }
}
```

But in the end I've got this:

[image]

Navigation bar changes colour to black. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=ColorNav;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=FALSE;
```

Comment: Thank you, i forgot about translucency :D

Answer (score 2):

I m not able to get why the color is changed automatically but you can use below code to set color, also check whether you have not set the any color for background of UITableView.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    } else {
        // iOS 7.0 or later     
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
_noviyVC.presentPlease = ^(UIViewController *controller)
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
};
```